# Automatic Excel Formula instead of writing by hand

Tags: excel, formula

[image]

Im trying to count the duplicated values between the 2 row so im using the formula as you can see it in the image =SUM(COUNTIFS(E4:S4,{"1","2","3"}))
so I have to write the numbers so I dont want write the numbers I want select the cells instead, any formula would do that? I already searched and tried many things but nothing seem to work

Comment: `=SUM(COUNTIFS(E4:S4,E5:S5))` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Put those values in cells - and refer to those cells as condition.
Next level: insert those values in a table, that you eg. call `FilterBy` and the column `values`

Then you can us this formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(E4:S4,filterBy[Values]))
```

Hat I don't understand: why are you using `SUM` - like this, it doesn't make sense, as `COUNTIFS` returns one value.

If you want to some all filtered values then you need this formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(E4:S4,E4:S4,filterBy[Values]))
```

[image]

Comment: I want them in row not in columns, thank but i didnt understand your answer and i dont need the filter too, I just want tell Excel to count how many numbers are the same between those 2 rows and just insert the result in the cell between the 2 rows as in the image

Comment: Ok - then you should edit your question and describe what you really want. Best would be to provide your data as table (using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation)) and showing us the expected output. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question.